# Why isn't my script able to locate my excel file when given correct filepath?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a .vbs script that opens two excel files and copies the contents of a sheet from the first file into the second file. It's supposed to run daily via task scheduler.

The script ran normally until the excel files in question were recently modified and slightly renamed - I went through the script and edited the filenames accordingly after the changes were made, triple checking that the names and filepaths matched up.

Everything ran fine for a few weeks after the changes but now the script fails immediately after starting, giving me an error claiming that the file can't be located even though the file is located at the given path. The error code is 800A03EC.
[image: error thrown by the script]

This is the first chunk of code in the script, including line 7 which seems to be throwing the error:

```
Dim objApp ' as excel object

Dim x, y ' as workbook
Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objApp.DisplayAlerts = False
objApp.Visible = False
Set x = objApp.Workbooks.Open("S:\Work (Public)\PORT MGMT & TRADING\PORT MGMT FORMS\ORION_FPFOCUS.xlsm")

Set y = objApp.Workbooks.Open("S:\Work (Public)\PORT MGMT & TRADING\PORT MGMT FORMS\FPFocusPasteSpecialValues.xlsb")
Dim WSx, WSy ' as excel worksheet
Set WSx = x.Worksheets("FPSUP")
Set WSy = y.Worksheets("FPFOCUS-COPY")
WSy.Range("B1").value = FormatDateTime(Now)
objApp.Application.Run "ORION_FPFOCUS.xlsm!Auto_Open"
```

The excel files in question are both located in the same directory:

```
S:\Work (Public)\PORT MGMT & TRADING\PORT MGMT FORMS\ORION_FPFOCUS.xlsm

S:\Work (Public)\PORT MGMT & TRADING\PORT MGMT FORMS\FPFocusPasteSpecialValues.xlsb
```

And the script is located here:

```
C:\Users\bserv\Documents\CopyFPFocus.vbs
```

The S drive isn't a physical drive, it's a virtual drive hosted by a service called Workplace. I can navigate through it and open the excel files manually just fine.

I initially thought it was a user privilege issue with task scheduler, but I've selected the 'run with highest privileges' option and the script is still failing. I also went through the privacy/trust settings in Excel to make sure the script wasn't being denied access, but I don't see any settings that would disable the script from working, and I also know that all these settings haven't changed since the script was working, so I don't see how they could be potential causes.

When I try running the code manually via cscript in the command line, it returns this error:

```
C:\Users\bserv\Documents\CopyFPFocus.vbs(25, 4) (null): The remote procedure call failed.
```

This is line 25 of the script for reference:

```
   objApp.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"
```

When I try again by running command prompt as an admin, I get the same error I got initially. Sorry, is it possible the file was moved renamed or deleted.

The part that really confuses me is that the script ran fine for some time after the changes - so I'm really unsure about what actually changed to cause this issue to randomly pop up.

One other thing I've noticed is that upon opening the excel files I get a popup saying they're in use and locked for editing by me. I can't remember if this popup was showing up before the issue started. The other users on the network have been accessing these files regularly long before the script started failing, so I don't see how that could be the issue. The error code/message also doesn't seem to correspond with this being the problem.

I'd appreciate any help or insight into this issue. Thank you!